# Detect Other Instance of Open Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have the user select an instance or open Workbook of Excel. The idea is to have a window that will display all open Instances of Excel and then display the Workbooks within these instances. I've done some self research and what I've found below...

```
Public Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias _
  "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Function ExcelInstances() As Long
    Dim hWndDesk As Long
    Dim hWndXL As Long

    'Get a handle to the desktop
    hWndDesk = GetDesktopWindow

    Do
        'Get the next Excel window
        hWndXL = FindWindowEx(GetDesktopWindow, hWndXL, _
          "XLMAIN", vbNullString)

        'If we got one, increment the count
        If hWndXL > 0 Then
            ExcelInstances = ExcelInstances + 1
        End If

        'Loop until we've found them all
    Loop Until hWndXL = 0
End Function
```

<s>**Problem:**</s>

When I ran the code, I am getting the error message:

> Compile Error:
>
> Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function or End Property

It's highlighting the first line in the code, and I believe it has something to do with the `"user32"` string?

**Question:**
This code will only give me a COUNT of how many instances of Excel are currently open. Is there any way to return the names of the instances and then another sub routine that would return the Workbooks within the instances as well? I've seen a solution making use of VB.Net; however I'd like to avoid this so that I can try to keep everything consolidated into a single Excel Spreadsheet (if possible).

Comment: `Public` declarations should be at the top of the module.

Comment: @BigBen Perfect, so that solved my first problem... Thanks for catching that :)

Comment: Unless you've taken specific measures, you have one instance of Excel with multiple documents, and they all can see each other through `Application.Workbooks`. If you have taken measures (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/ or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165211/how-to-force-excel-to-open-in-a-new-instance-by-default) and you do in fact have several instances of Excel, it's probably the intended behaviour that you don't see the other instances.